# Change theme per project in Pycharm

Tags: pycharm

Is there a way to change the PyCharm Theme for each opened project? I often have 2 different projects in 2 different desktops. I'd like each one to have a different Theme. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Configure PyCharm Dark Mode per Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67227703/configure-pycharm-dark-mode-per-project)

Answer (score 2):

I've had the exact same issue with JetBrains products, so I built a plugin that solves exactly that, it gives you the option to choose different colors for the title bar, which is seen in the task view mode, and thus helps you differentiate between open projects by color!

[image: Usage example]

You can download it by searching Project-Color in the JetBrains plugin marketplace window on your IDE, or from my [GitHub repository](https://github.com/nowtilous/Project-Color), where you can find more usage examples and a detailed explanation of the available features.

Answer (score 1):

The appearance and theme settings in PyCharm are per-application, not per-project. The only chance to have per-project colors is to use Settings | File Colors and to assign a color to the "Project files" scope. That color assignment is per-project, not per-application.

Comment: pycharm should provide this... some settings should be on project level not on app level... it's 2020 but still it's not available... sad

Answer (score 0):

There are few alternatives described here:
https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206184059-Colour-Theme-per-project-

My favorite is

> Set Background Image