# Configure PyCharm Dark Mode per Project

Tags: python, pycharm, keyboard-shortcuts, settings, darkmode

Is it possible to configure PyCharm dark mode on a project-by-project basis?

Me and my colleague are sharing the same machine to run some simulations and we both use PyCharm, but we have separate workspace/projects. I love `IntelliJ Light` but my colleague prefers `Darcula`. So, is it possible to configure different themes for different projects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easily switching the UI theme (from IntelliJ Light to Darcula darkmode) can be done using the `Quick Switch Scheme` action through the default keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl + `</kbd>.

[image]

[image]

Switching the UI can also be done through the breadcrumb `File` `>` `Settings` `>` `Appearance & Behavior` `>` `Appearance` `>` `Theme` shown in the screenshot.

[image]

This might not be entirely clear from the PyCharm documentation, at the time of this writing, because searching for the action using the intuitive keyword "theme" gives no results.

> [User interface themes](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/user-interface-themes.html)
>
> You can assign a shortcut to the Theme action, so that you can quickly switch between themes.

However, the IntelliJ IDEA documentation does explicitly state the name of the action

> [Use the quick switcher](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/user-interface-themes.html#e5aeff6a)
>
> 1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>`` ` ``</kbd> to execute the View | `Quick Switch Scheme` action.

---

---

Directly answering the question as it is asked:

> Is it possible to configure PyCharm dark mode on a project-by-project basis?

I don't think so. The Theme configuration is an IDE wide setting, not a project setting. Given the ease of changing Theme with a couple of keyboard strokes considering other approaches isn't really worth the effort.

I tried searching the [configuration files](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/directories-used-by-the-ide-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs.html) but couldn't find the Theme setting, probably because the Theme itself is a plugin that needs to run an event so the action of changing themes is more complex than a simple entry in a configuration file. For example, this is what the [log file](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/setting-log-options.html) looks like after the action of changing theme:

```
2021-04-27 08:59:57,336 [ 416653]   INFO - cloudConfig.CloudConfigManager - === Start.Edit: [colors.scheme.xml] |false| === 
2021-04-27 08:59:57,336 [ 416653]   INFO - cloudConfig.CloudConfigManager - === Start.Edit: [laf.xml] |true| === 
2021-04-27 08:59:58,352 [ 417669]   INFO - cloudConfig.CloudConfigManager - === doConnect === 
2021-04-27 08:59:58,352 [ 417669]   INFO - cloudConfig.CloudConfigManager - === getConnectionState === 
2021-04-27 08:59:59,433 [ 418750]   INFO - cloudConfig.CloudConfigManager - === End.Update: [C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\PyCharm2021.1\jba_config\colors.scheme.xml, C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\PyCharm2021.1\jba_config\laf.xml] ===
```