# Why are image colors distorted in PyCharm?

Tags: image, matplotlib, pycharm, python-imaging-library, darkmode

I wanted to read in JPG with `Pillow` and then show it with `imshow` from `matplotlib`, but the image doesn't look like the original file. What's wrong?

```
img = Image.open("my_pics/cat.jpg")
arr = np.array(img)
plt.imshow(arr)
```

[image]

Comment: You can use ```Ctrl + ` ``` for the theme quick switcher, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67280505).

Comment: @bad_coder Sorry for the dumb question, but how to you type the second charater? In my german keyboard layout you type ` by using Shift + the button left to backspace, so it's a combination as well and not a single key.

Comment: See the first post I linked, the name of the action to remap is "quick switch" (use the search within the keymap dialogue) if the backtick character ` isn't convenient on your keyboard you should remap it.

Comment: @bad_coder For which layouts is ` its own key? US?

Comment: The backtick is never it's own key afaik but in countries that use it as [diactiric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diacritic) it's used with Shift and placed conveniently on the keyboard. (I think the shift only shows in the keymap for upper case characters not for diacritics.)

Answer (score 10):

You can go to `Preferences -> Languages & Frameworks -> Jupyter` and **uncheck** `invert image outputs for dark themes`. You will need to reopen the editor to apply the change.

Comment: I just wasted half a day on this, and was ready to go back to colab. Thankyou!!

Answer (score 4):

The Dark-Mode in Pycharm alters the image (as of Feb. 22nd '22).

Maybe JetBrains will patch this in future updates.

Comment: If you fill a bug, possibly they will correct it earlier.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi I hope so too, I just wanted to save other people the hassle I had to go through.